# json shuffling via jqueryui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I've an json array

```
[    {  
    "song_name":"Gerua",
    "file":"Gerua.mp3",
    "img_src":"436264562.jpg",
},
{   
    "song_name":"Manma Emotion Jaage",
    "file":"Jaage.mp3",
    "img_src":"436264562.jpg",

},
{  
    "song_name":"Janam Janam",
    "file":"Janam.mp3",
    "img_src":"436264562.jpg",
}]
```

I've used jqueryui sortable to display this array in below manner.
[image]

user can shuffle this list.

I want to shuffle the json array as user selected, when user clicks update button.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kunalbhatia/48v4h4a2/3/)

Comment: So you're wanting the json object to correspond with the order of the DOM elements

Comment: yes, if its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it. Introduced a temp array and a mediaid attribute to li, read dom values on update button click, saved values to temp array in order of user shuffled via mediaid, copied temp array to main array.

```
$("#update").click(function(e) {
 temp_json=[];
 $.each($("#sortable>li"), function(key, val) {
  temp_json.push(songs_json[$(val).attr('mediaid')]);
 });
 songs_json=temp_json;
 $("#updatedjson").html(JSON.stringify(songs_json, undefined, 2));
});
```

[check it out!](http://jsfiddle.net/kunalbhatia/48v4h4a2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

My favourite algorith to shuffle an array is [Durstenfeld shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm), Here is a JavaScript implementation of the:

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Use it like:

```
shuffleArray(yourArrayOfObject); // Will return shuffled array.
```

**The running time of this algorithm is O(n)**

Comment: user can shuffle the list, its not random.